# Declare events wehen icon is clicked in AJAX request

Tags: javascript, ajax, events

I wrote this code for getting data from a device table and shows in a table created in JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tableresponsive = $("#table-responsive");
    tableresponsive.text("Loading data from JSON source...");
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "url to get all devise ", 
      success: function(result) {
        var output =
          "<table class=\"table table-hover mb-0\"><thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Devise</th><th>Symbole</th><th>Taux de change </th><th width=\"110\">Actions</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
        $.each(result.records, function(key, val) {
    output+=`
        <tr>
 
            <td>` + val.devise_id + `</td>
            <td>` + val.devise_name + `</td>
            <td>` + val.symbole + `</td>
            <td>` + val.taux_de_change + `</td>
            <!-- 'action' buttons -->
            <td class="td-actions"><a href="update_devise.html?id=` + val.devise_id + `"><i class="la la-edit edit"></i></a><a id="`+val.devise_id+`"  ><i class="la la-close delete"></i></a></td>
        </tr>`;
$("#val.devise_id").click(function() {
  console.log("yes");
});
});
 output += "</tbody></table>";
        tableresponsive.html(output);
      }
    });
  });
```

this work well,
[image]

Now I want to declare an event when I click in icon that have `class="edit"` and `id=val.devise_id`.  I tried this code for testing:

```
$("#val.devise_id").click(function() {
  console.log("yes");
});
```

But it doesn't work. I think I have a problem with declaring `id=val.devise_id`.

How I can fixe this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try delegating the event & do it outside the ajax

```
$("#table-responsive").on('click,'#val.devise_id',function() {
  console.log("yes");
});
```